# Save the same element from XML file as an array C#

Tags: c#, xml

it could be a silly question, but i want ta ask, how can I save the same element from an .XML file with different content as an array.
Example XML:

```
<ithem>
<description>description1</description>
<description>description2</description>
<description>description3</description>
</ithem>
```

then string [] descriptions will be

```
descriptions[0] = "description1";
descriptions[1] = "description2";
descriptions[2] = "description3";
```

Please help!

Comment: You have described the task, but what exactly is the question? How far have you come when you implemented it, and what part of the task is posing an obstacle? Reading the Xml file? Finding the values? Writing an array?

Comment: Which xml technology do you use? Anyway. Whatever you use should support XPath in one form or another and you would want something like ``doc.SelectNodes("/ithem/description")`` to get your nodelist of description fields. Then you can use that to create your array.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to XML it would be:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(xmlFile);
string[] descriptions = root.Descendants("description").Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
```

or

```
string[] descriptions = root.Element("ithem").Elements("description").Select(e => e.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlDocument to parse the XML :

```
        var map = new XmlDocument();
        map.Load("path_to_xml_file"); // you can also load it directly from a string

        var descriptions = new List<string>();
        var nodes = map.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("ithem/description");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            var description = Convert.ToString(node.Value);
            descriptions.Add(description);
        }
```

And you get it as an array from:

```
  descriptions.ToArray();
```